# flutter null safety Regex group error : A value string? can't be assigned to type String

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to make flutter nullsafety migration, but I have an error with match.group(1);
The error is : A value string? can't be assigned to type String

Here is my code

late String date_modify ;

```
RegExp regExp = new RegExp(          
          r"(.{0,10}(?!\w))",
        );

    var date=DateTime.now();
    DateTime daysfromnow = date.add(new Duration(days: 0));

    var match = regExp.firstMatch("$daysfromnow");
    date_modify = match.group(1); 

var _lastConso_sec = date_modify!=null ? DateTime.parse(date_modify) : DateTime.now();
```

If I convert  `late String date_modify; =>  late String? date_modify ;`

It's ok with

```
date_modify = match!.group(1);
```

but I have now problem with `DateTime.parse(date_modify)`

the argument type String ? can't be assigned to the parameter type String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the data type of `date_modify` from `String` to `String?`

```
String? dateModify;
date_modify = match!.group(1); 
DateTime.parse(dateModify!);
```

Comment: If I convert late String date_modify; => late String? date_modify ;

It's ok with

date_modify = match!.group(1); 
but I have now problem with DateTime.parse(date_modify)

the argument type String ? can't be assigned to the parameter type String

Comment: String? date_modify, DateTime.parse(date_modify!). Please remove late

Comment: late String? date_modify  or String? date_modify I have same problem with DateTime.parse(date_modify)

Comment: it's ok with date_modify! thank you !!